# Marquee + Draggable + Droppable not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a simple game, which consists on a set of scrolling elements (to achieve this I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee)), which I'm intended to drag and drop into a set of four containers (using jQueryUI's draggable and droppable) and match if they're in the correct container (imagine 30 animals scrolling on the bottom, and you have to sort it according if they're birds, mammals, reptiles, etc.). After 30 seconds the game ends and it shows the number of correct/wrong elements.

The problem that I'm having currently is that the marquee and the draggable+droppable are working fine by their own, but when I combine them, the Marquee plugin interferes with the droppable behaviour. I am still kind of a newbie in jQuery programming, so I don't know if there's a way to stack the functions, or how to order the elements.

I've put everything (just barebones):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nS3bz/)

I've also tried using animate() to scroll the items, but when the items are dropped on the boxes, it only shows the confirmation when the animation stops:

```
$("#itemsHolder li").each(function(i){
    var $li = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $li.animate({'left': '500px'}, 7000, 'linear', function(){ $li.hide(); });
    }, 1500 * i );
});
```

I was using jQuery because I have a pretty slight understanding of it, but if anybody got any better approach (HTML5, any magic program that makes everything magically, NO FLASH) or some tutorials for this I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Maybe reverse the order of the 2 (plugin/dragable). Is your jQuery loaded before the other scripting?

Comment: jquery is loaded in the <head>, the script on the bottom. I tried reversing the order of the scripts, but the result is the same. :-/